# Help understanding/proving a simple claim about sinks and sources.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading an introductory differential equations text where the author makes a claim that I feel should be obvious, but I cannot prove to myself.

The author proposes a  first-order, autonomous differential equation of the form $x' = f(x)$, where solution $x$ is a function of real variable $t$, possessing two equilibrium points, $x_l$ and $x_r$, such that $f'(x_l)>0$ and $f'(x_r)<0$. I assume these are derivatives w/ respect to $x$.

**Because of the sign of their derivatives, he says $x_l$ is a source and $x_r$ is a sink.**

Would someone please provide a hint on how to prove the previous statement?
I've tried working along the lines of
$$\frac{f(y)-f(x_l)}{y-x_l}=\frac{x'(y)-x'(x_l)}{y-x_l}=\frac{x'(y)}{y-x_l}>0$$
for all $y$ in some neighborhood of $x_l$, but now I'm unsure of how to work $t$ into the picture. The mixture of derivatives w.r.t $x$ and $t$ and the function $x$ being treated as a variable makes my head spin and blocks me from any good intuition. Apart from help with this specific problem, advice on how to think about/approach these problems would be welcome.

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: As far as intuition, I suggest you think of $f$ as defining a vector field on the timeline. That is, $f(0)$ indicates the direction and length of an arrow sticking out either left or right from the point $0$ on the real line. That $f(x_l) = 0$ and $f'(x_l) > 0$ then tells you that $x_l$ is the point at which your arrow switches from pointing left to pointing right. Visually, it will literally look like arrows are flowing out from $x_l$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $x_0$ is an equilibrium point then $f(x_0) = 0$ and near $x_0$ the system can be described as

$$
\frac{d}{dt}(x_0+\delta(t)) = f(x_0)+f'(x_0)\delta(t) + O(\delta^2(t))
$$

or

$$
\dot\delta = f'(x_0)\delta
$$

now if $f'(x_0) = -k$ with $k > 0$ then

$$
\dot\delta + k\delta = 0\Rightarrow \delta = C_0e^{-k t}
$$

showing that $x_0$ is asymptotically stable (sink). Analogously if $f'(x_0) > 0$ the point is unstable (source).

Comment: Could you please define $\delta(t)$? And your $O$?

Comment: $\delta(t) = \Delta x$ and we are using the Taylor series expansion for the point $x_0$ so $O(\cdot)$ has the usual meaning in this expansion. We are assuming that the dynamic system is one-dimensional.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to catch up now. We define $x(t) \equiv x_0 + \delta(t)$ and then display that Taylor expansion for $f(x)$ centered at $x_0$. I follow everything, except for what happens to the $O(\delta^2(t))$ term. Why do you get to drop that?

Comment: We drop that because we are making a linear approximation to $f(x)$ at $x_0$ so we discard higher order terms. ($\delta^2$) and for small $|\delta|$ we have $\delta^2 << |\delta|$